# How to fix "java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException:" for %s in Java code

Tags: java, formatting

I am coding for my Java class and I am getting a "java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException:" Error when I use %s for the System.out.printf .

I've tried keeping it all in the "    " marks and I have tried separating out.

This is my code:

```
    System.out.println("your bill is: ");
        System.out.printf("%30s", "Item" + "%10s", "Quantity", "%-10s", "Price", "%-10s", "Total");
        System.out.printf("\n %s" + firstItem + "%10.2f" + firstItemQuant + "%10f" + firstItemPrice + "%10.2f" + firstItemTotal);
        System.out.printf("\n %s" + secondItem + "%10.2f" + secondItemQuant + "%10f" + secondItemPrice + "%10.2f" + secondItemTotal);
        System.out.printf("\n %s" + thirdItem + "10.2f" + thirdItemQuant + "%10f" + thirdItemPrice + "%10.2f" + thirdItemTotal);
        System.out.printf("\n %s -----------");
        System.out.printf("\n %s Subtotal %50f" + subtotal);
```

I am getting this as a result:

```
    your bill is: 
                      Item%10s
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at assignment1.main(assignment1.java:67)
```

I just want the bill to be formatted into columns

Comment: Yeah, you're using it wrong.  [Have a look here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).  The first argument to `printf` has to be the one with all the `%` signs in.  Subsequent arguments are the ones that get substituted in.

Comment: `...printf("Item: %s, Quantity: %d\n", item, quant);` (first argument is string with format, 2nd and further arguments are values to be *inserted* into the format string at placehholders) Something is almost always wrong if using concatenation in a printf....

Comment: Note: The platform-agnostic line separator of `printf()`/`Formatter` is [`%n`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dls) rather than [`\n`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).